# Why can char be initialized to nullptr in a std::array, but not by itself?

Tags: c++

This code **doesn't** compile (using gcc 9.3)...

```
int main() {
    char bar = nullptr; //error: cannot convert ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘char’ in initialization
}
```

But this code **does** compile...

```
#include <array>
int main() {
    std::array<char, 1> foo = {nullptr}; // foo[0] == char(0), why?
}
```

Why is there a distinction?

Comment: The 2nd one doesn't compile on my machine.  `JakeSchmidt.cpp:3:32: error: cannot initialize an array element of type 'char' with an rvalue of type 'nullptr_t`.

Comment: Are you using MSVC? Both [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/r94bmDEWaCKZ56tZ) and [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0CnSM7hGcVpyc0bX) can't compile.

Comment: @songyuanyao I'm using built in gcc 9.3 on ubuntu

Comment: probably just a compiler bug then

Comment: Probably. GCC 10 has the error and I can reproduce the lack of one with GCC 9.3 on Compiler Explorer.

Comment: It looks like GCC 9 accepts that code, but not GCC 8 or GCC 10.

Comment: Always compile with *warnings enabled*. For gcc/clang add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow` to your compile string. For VS add `/W3`. For all other compilers check the documentation regarding enabling warnings. gcc 7.4.1 issues the error, `cannot convert ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘char’`

Comment: I think it is a compiler bug if no diagnostic is issued (and you are in conforming mode)

Comment: @David C. Rankin I did, it's a compiler bug, I only didn't use ```-Wshadow``` because this is a test case.

Comment: Okay -- mystery solved. I have gcc 7 and 10 to test on. Seems there was some sort of regression in gcc 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why can char be initialized to nullptr in a std::array

It can't. The shown program is ill-formed in C++.

When an ill-formed program compiles, there are typically two possibilities:

1. It is a language extension.
2. It is a compiler bug.

In this case, I think it is the latter. The bug reproduces in GCC 9, but appears to have been fixed in GCC 10.